# Circle Ci job on tags matching regex

Tags: circleci

I have following circleci. The problem is that npm_publish job is executed no matter what tag is set and it should be executed only on tag matching regex(regex /v[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)*/)

What I'm doing wrong?

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build_and_test:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:7.10
    working_directory: ~/checkout-dir      
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: yarn install
      - run: npm run build
      - run: npm test
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-repo-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_SHA1 }}
          paths:
            - ~/checkout-dir
  npm_publish:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:7.10
    working_directory: ~/checkout-dir            
    steps:
      - restore_cache:
          key: v1-repo-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_SHA1 }}
      - run:
          name: setup npm
          command: |
            echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN" >> ~/.npmrc
      - run: npm publish

workflows:
  version: 2
  build:
    jobs:
      - build_and_test
  build_and_deploy:
    jobs:
      - build_and_test:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/
            branches:
              only: master
      - npm_publish:
          requires:
            - build_and_test
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/
            branches:
              only: master
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from trying to debug your regex, which isn't my strong suite, my first suggestion is to fix the branch matching. You currently have:

```
        branches:
          only: master
```

for the `npm_publish` job, which means that aside from tags, that job is slated to run on every commit to the master branch which doesn't seem to be what you want.

To help further with the regex, what is an example regex you'd want to match and one that you don't?

**Update**

Here's what I would use instead based on your comments:

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  build_and_deploy:
    jobs:
      - build_and_test:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/
      - npm_publish:
          requires:
            - build_and_test
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/
            branches:
              ignore: /.*/
```

So the way this Workflow config works, the `build_and_test` job runs on every commit push to GitHub (regardless of branch) and the `npm_publish` job will only run on a Git tag push for Git tags that match the regex `/v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/`.

Respectfully,

Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI

Comment: Thx, what i meant is to run npm_publish only on commits to master and only when that commit has a tag matching regex. I see from your response that setting only: master will be triggered on every commit without taking into consideration tag regex. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I see. So Git tags don't belong to a branch. In this case, it's it's own thing you you'd want to remove matching on master at all. I'll update my answer with an example.